# golang ToUpper struct string fields

Tags: go

I have a struct like this:

```
type CvssV3 struct {
    BaseScore             *float32 `json:"baseScore"`
    AttackVector          *string  `json:"attackVector"`
    AttackComplexity      *string  `json:"attackComplexity"`
    PrivilegesRequired    *string  `json:"privilegesRequired"`
    UserInteraction       *string  `json:"userInteraction"`
    Scope                 *string  `json:"scope"`
    ConfidentialityImpact *string  `json:"confidentialityImpact"`
    IntegrityImpact       *string  `json:"integrityImpact"`
    AvailabilityImpact    *string  `json:"availabilityImpact"`
}
cvssV3 = CvssV3{
      "baseScore" : 4.3,
      "attackVector" : "Network",
      "attackComplexity" : "Low",
      "privilegesRequired" : "Low",
      "userInteraction" : "None",
      "scope" : "Unchanged",
      "confidentialityImpact" : "None",
      "integrityImpact" : "Low",
      "availabilityImpact" : "None"
    }
```

I want to ToUpper the string type values, expected result:

```
cvssV3 = CvssV3{
      "baseScore" : 4.3,
      "attackVector" : "NETWORK",
      "attackComplexity" : "LOW",
      "privilegesRequired" : "LOW",
      "userInteraction" : "NONE",
      "scope" : "UNCHANGED",
      "confidentialityImpact" : "NONE",
      "integrityImpact" : "LOW",
      "availabilityImpact" : "NONE"
    }
```

how to deal with it?

each field use strings.ToUpper is Inelegant

Comment: An option would be to declare a custom string type that implements json.Unmarshaler and converts to upper while unmarshaling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to upcase the string fields:

```
// Get a modifiable reflect value for cvssV3.
v := reflect.ValueOf(&cvssV3).Elem()
// For each field ...
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    f := v.Field(i)
    // If field is a string, then UPPER.
    if f.Kind() == reflect.String {
        f.SetString(strings.ToUpper(f.String()))
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/xi7dp0ct6Ni

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the fields of your struct using the [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Field) library.

```go
st := reflect.TypeOf(cvssV3)
for i := 0; i < st.NumField(); i++ {
    field := st.Field(i)
    if reflect.TypeOf(field) ==  "string"{
        // apply toUpper
    } 
}
```